# Load Excel File From a file and Update Cells Values in Memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

Based on this article : [Insert text into a cell in a spreadsheet document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc861607.aspx)

I want to load an Excel file in memory and update some cells values and send it to client as a download attachment.

I know that there is an overload for `Open` method that use `Stream` but I don't know How I can load Excel file to it.

How I can Load Excel File From a file and Update Cells Values in Memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article in this link explains in detail when and how an Excel workbook can be opened from a Stream: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478410.aspx

Summarizing: there's a special overload of the Open method that accepts a Stream object and a Boolean (whether the Excel file can be edited or not).